# How to fire 2 different click events with the same data in JQuery + AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want the first click event to get the data ready. Then I want the second click event to deliver the data. Basically I need to fire one event when I click on .modal_thumbnails, then I want to fire the other when I click on #set_image, but it does not work obviously.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var link, image;
    $(".modal_thumbnails").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            var href = $('#user_id').text();
            var splitted = href.split(':');
            link = splitted[splitted.length - 1];
            image = $(this).attr('src');
            var tarr = image.split('/');
            image = tarr[tarr.length - 1];
        }
    });

    $("#set_image").click(function () {
        $(".jumbotron img").attr('src', image + '?id=' + link);
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <h4 id="user_id">Userd Id: 48</h4>
    <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
        <a href="">
            <img height=200 width=250 class="modal_thumbnails" src="http://placehold.it/750x450" alt=""/>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<!--First Row -->
<div class="row">
    <div class=".jumbotron">
        <h3>JumboTron</h3>
        <img src="" alt="image_here"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <a id="set_image" href="#">CLICK HERE TO SET PICTURE</a>
</div>
```

Comment: When you set the variables in the first click event handler, you are not setting them globally. Create global variables to set values to and then access those global variables in your second click function. So before your click function, and after your ready function write `var link, image;` and then remove `var` from `var link ...` and `var image ...` in your first click even handler

Comment: It's not working, Should I make the other variables global too?

Comment: Do you have any HTML that I can try testing it with? If you can create a jsfiddle or a codepen for example, I can help more. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I don't, since it's php, but I will make one in a couple mins, if this helps.

Comment: Your code looks correct. The only issue I can see is the variables you're trying to access in your second click even handler don't exist, so making them global variables would solve that issue at least. From what I understand of your code is that the user is selecting their profile picture (or something along the line) and you're sending the image's name of the image they choose as well as its path to your update_preferences.php file for processing and it is returning data (whatever that is) and you're setting an url parameter to the image's path

Comment: Another issue I just noticed with your code is that you are setting the image variable twice. This could be causing you issues

Comment: Basically, In one click on a image I'm  grabbing the image name, and the id from another field. in another click I'm sending that data.

Comment: var link, image; $(".modal_thumbnails").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            var href = $('#user_id').text();
            var splitted = href.split(':');
            link = splitted[splitted.length - 1];
            image = $(this).attr('src');
            var tarr = image.split('/');
            image = tarr[tarr.length - 1];
        }
    });

Comment: Copy the code above, tell me if it works?

Comment: Also, have you tested to ensure each variable is being set to the correct variables? If not put the following code in your first function and try clicking an element: alert("href: "+href+"\nsplitted: "+splitted+"\nlink: "+link+"\nimage: "+image+"\ntarr: "+tarr

Comment: I updated the main code with html and your code and nothing. Try the main code I updated and let met know, please, thanks

Comment: You're passing `?id=` into the image's url. Pass only the static url unless you're adding it to the href attribute in a link

Comment: I put alert(link) on the second function and it comes undefined, it should contain the data from the first function

Comment: Put it in the first function and let me know what values you obtain

Comment: I get 48, the expected value

Comment: I finally found the solution, I having the global variables in mind like you told me.

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution, make sure you read up on scope a bit if you don't already know about it: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: Thanks, I do know about scope, it's just for some reason, JS confuses me, or maybe I'm seeing it harder than it is. I have a PHP background!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var image, link, href, splitted;
    $(".modal_thumbnails").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        href = $('#user_id').text();
        splitted = href.split(':');
        link = splitted[splitted.length - 1];
        image = $(this).attr('src');
        image = image.split('/');
        image = image[image.length - 1];
    });
    $("#set_image").click(function () {
        if ($(".modal_thumbnails").hasClass('selected')) {
            alert(image + link);
        } else {
            alert('no');
        }
    });
});
```